# Sudden memory consumption jump resulting in out of memory exception while processing huge text file

Tags: c#, .net, stream, out-of-memory, task-parallel-library

I need to process a very large text file (6-8 GB). I wrote the code attached below. Unfortunately, every time output file reaches (being created next to source file) reaches ~2GB, I observe **sudden jump in memory consumption** (~100MB to few GBs) and in result - **out of memory exception**.

Debugger indicates that OOM occurs at `while ((tempLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)`
I am targeting .NET 4.7 and x64 architecture only.
Single line is at most 50 character long.

*I can workaround this and split original file to smaller parts not to face the problem while processing and merge resuls back to one file at the end, but would like not to do it.*

Code:

```
public async Task PerformDecodeAsync(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        var allLines = CountLines(sourcePath);
        long processedlines = default;
        using (File.Create(targetPath));
        var streamWriter = File.AppendText(targetPath);
        var decoderBlockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>(1000);
        var writerBlockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>(1000);

        var producer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(sourcePath), Encoding.Default, true))
            {
                string tempLine;
                while ((tempLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    decoderBlockingCollection.Add(tempLine);
                }
                decoderBlockingCollection.CompleteAdding();

            }
        });
        var consumer1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var line in decoderBlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                short decodeCounter = 0;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var singleChar in line)
                {

                    var positionInDecodeKey = decodingKeysList[decodeCounter].IndexOf(singleChar);

                    if (positionInDecodeKey > 0)
                        builder.Append(model.Substring(positionInDecodeKey, 1));
                    else
                        builder.Append(singleChar);


                    if (decodeCounter > 18)
                        decodeCounter = 0;
                    else ++decodeCounter;
                }
                writerBlockingCollection.TryAdd(builder.ToString());
                Interlocked.Increment(ref processedlines);
                if (processedlines == (long)allLines)
                    writerBlockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
            }
        });
        var writer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var line in writerBlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
            }
        });
        Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer1, writer);
    }
```

Solutions, as well as advices how to optimize it a little more is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which line the exception occures?

Comment: Was this the first way you thought of to do this? Because I'd have composed `File.ReadLines`, an overload of `Select` that supplies an `index` and `File.WriteAllLines`, all nicely just keeping everything as enumerables, rather than leaping to concurrent collections and running explicit tasks.

Comment: @Nehorai Debugging session shows while ((tempLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) as the place where OOM occurs.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, the first way i though about was to use producer-consumer pattern to pararellize work. Could you provide me with a code sample? (i suspect you advice to use LINQ/PLINQ)

Comment: I am terribly sorry. OOM seems to be caused by the file I test on. I took another 8GB+ one and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, I'd probably go for something simpler first, unless or until it's demonstrated that it's not performing well. As Adi said in their answer, this work appears to be I/O bound - so there seems little benefit in creating multiple tasks for it.

```
publiv void PerformDecode(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(targetPath,File.ReadLines(sourcePath).Select(line=>{
        short decodeCounter = 0;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var singleChar in line)
        {
            var positionInDecodeKey = decodingKeysList[decodeCounter].IndexOf(singleChar);
            if (positionInDecodeKey > 0)
                builder.Append(model.Substring(positionInDecodeKey, 1));
            else
                builder.Append(singleChar);

            if (decodeCounter > 18)
                decodeCounter = 0;
            else ++decodeCounter;
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }));
}
```

Now, of course, this code actually blocks until it's done, which is why I've not marked it `async`. But then, so did yours, and it should have been warning about that already.

(You could try using PLINQ instead of LINQ for the `Select` portion but honestly, the amount of *processing* we're doing here looks trivial; Profile first before applying any such change)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Actually, yours is a little faster on IO than mine, but takes inly 30% of CPU load (compared to 80% of my solution).
Nevertheless, almost at the same moment... program crashes!
Same exception - after output file reaches ~2GB memory consumption rises blazing fast causing out of memory exception.
To be fully precise I am not making all of this at FAT16 (2GB file size limit) but on NTFS

Comment: It seems that the error is caused by limitation of Stream being somewhere under the writer. Flushing it periodically should aid the problem.

Comment: As a side-question: by "using PLINQ", you suggest for adding AsPararell() to the select? Do you recommend something else tied to pararellizing the this LINQ query?

Comment: *This* code shouldn't be causing any odd memory consumption. I'd note that I removed the `CountLines` from mine because I couldn't see a good reason for it. Is it possible you've reintroduced it and *it* is the cause of the bad memory usage? (I removed it since the only way it could work would be to read the file itself to count them, and the one thing sure to slow down any I/O work is duplicating it)

Comment: I didn't reintroduce it. I have read some other posts on SO and it seems that `StreamReader` throws OOM while after it reads 2GB of data. I am actually try to solve this issue..

Comment: @MikelThief - the above code doesn't use a `StreamReader`. But even if it did, there isn't a general problem with that type. Almost every time someone reports an OOM with types such as these, it turns out that *elsewhere* they're trying to force the entire file into memory. I'd suggest you take a process dump when the OOM is getting hit and then use WinDbg/SOS to work out *what's using memory* and where it's rooted.

Comment: I assure that `PerformDecode()` contains only your code and still it throws OOM.

Comment: I assure you, that now my PerformDecode() only contains your code and it still throws the exception.

Comment: @MikelThief - yes, so **look elsewhere**. This may be where the error is *raised*, but it's not what's exhausting the address space.

Answer (score 0):

As the work you are doing is mostly IO bound, you aren't really gaining anything from parallelization. It also looks to me like (correct me if I'm wrong) that your transformation algorithm doesn't depend on you reading the file line-by-line, so I would recommend instead doing something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    //Setup streams for testing
    using(var inputStream = new MemoryStream())
    using(var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var inputWriter = new StreamWriter(inputStream))
    using (var outputReader = new StreamReader(outputStream))
    {
        //Write test string and rewind stream
        inputWriter.Write("abcdefghijklmnop");
        inputWriter.Flush();
        inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var inputBuffer = new byte[5];
        var outputBuffer = new byte[5];
        int inputLength;
        while ((inputLength = inputStream.Read(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++)
            {
                //transform each character
                outputBuffer[i] = ++inputBuffer[i];
            }

            //Write to output
            outputStream.Write(outputBuffer, 0, inputLength);
        }

        //Read for testing
        outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var output = outputReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        //Outputs: "bcdefghijklmnopq"
    }

}
```

Obviously, you would be using FileStreams instead of MemoryStreams, and you can increase the buffer length to something much larger (as this was just a demonstrative example). Also as your original method is Async, you use the async variants of Stream.Write and Stream.Read

Comment: actually, i need to take line by line as the alghorhitm processing the lines needs to have full line avalaible to give me a correct result.
I believe pararelization here can help (correct me if i am wrong), because if I read from DISK1 and write to DISK2, i don't need to wait for a write operation to complete to read another line.

Comment: Okay yes, I see it now, the `decodeCounter` resets for every line. As for between 2 disks, the FileStream actually writes to an internal buffer first before "flushing" to disk periodically, so the performance penalty for waiting for a write will actually be much less than you think

Comment: Thanks for clarification. 
I found out that somehow StreamReader is responsible for throwing the exception. Even if i apply DiscardBufferedData() it does not help. Seems it has some problems reading more than 2GB. I am trying to get to know.. why? Any ideas?